# How to pass a parameter to PdfAction.JavaScript(jscode, stapmer.Writer)

Tags: javascript, c#, itext

```
// test
AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
var fields = form.Fields;
var fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys;
foreach (string fieldKey in fieldKeys)
{
    if (fieldKey.Contains("timeholder"))
    {                    
        float[] fieldPos = form.GetFieldPositions(fieldKey);
        var fieldLlx = fieldPos[1];
        var fieldLly = fieldPos[2];
        var fieldUrx = fieldPos[3];
        var fieldUry = fieldPos[4];
        Rectangle recTime = new Rectangle(fieldLlx, fieldLly, fieldUrx, 
            fieldUry);
        PushbuttonField btnTime = new PushbuttonField(stamper.Writer, recTime, 
            "post");
        PdfAnnotation timeButton = btnTime.Field;

        timeButton.Action = PdfAction.JavaScript(
            "var date = this.getField(\"03 Time timeholder\"); date.value = new 
            Date().toLocaleTimeString();", stamper.Writer);
        stamper.AddAnnotation(timeButton, 1);
    }
}
```

---

The above codes work properly, my question is 
how to use fieldKey to replace "03 Time timeholder", the following is a segment of javascript.

"var date = this.getField(\"03 Time timeholder\"); date.value = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();"

Thanks in advance.
Tony

Comment: You mean `"var date = this.getField(\""+fieldKey+"\"); date.value = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();"`?

Comment: mkl, you are great, it works!

Comment: Ok, I'll make that an answer you can mark as accepted answer by clicking the tick in its upper left.

Comment: Clicking on the up-arrow isn't forbidden either :D

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is accordingly change the JavaScript string you initialize the `PdfAction` with:

```
timeButton.Action = PdfAction.JavaScript(
    "var date = this.getField(\"" + fieldKey + "\"); date.value = new 
    Date().toLocaleTimeString();", stamper.Writer);
```

This suffices because you create an individual JavaScript scriptlet for each timeholder field and the field name, therefore, can be hard-coded in each scriptlet.

As far as I know this is not uncommon in PDF JavaScript event handlers.

Comment: Thank you mkl, obviously, you are a PDF expert.